# `git clone --reference` with a blobless clone gives fatal errors

Tags: git, git-clone

I'm trying to speed up a full clone by referencing an existing clone made with `--filter=blob:none`.

(Yes, I actually want to create another repository, not do something like `fetch --unshallow`)

I hoped that the missing objects would be sourced from the appropriate remote as they usually are, but no:

```
% git clone --filter=blob:none --quiet --bare git@github.com:HaleTom/dotfiles.git blobless
% git clone --reference blobless git@github.com:HaleTom/dotfiles.git new-clone
Cloning into 'new-clone'...
error: cannot read object e8b079d8b0914612a87fb89ecd2d3c67eebe3628 '.gitignore'
<snip>
error: cannot read object e5bf7b3310b268d7bbd15edec5d1aecd7b87e2d5 'zsh/.config/zsh/zle'
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded, but checkout failed.
You can inspect what was checked out with 'git status'
and retry with 'git restore --source=HEAD :/'
```

Regarding `--filter=blob:none`, the `git clone` manpage says:

> filter out all blobs (file contents) until needed by Git

Why does this error out rather than fetching the blobs when they are needed as per the manual?

Comment: "*Why does this error out rather than fetching the blobs when they are needed as per the manual?*" Probably a bug in Git; blobless clone used in a not-anticipated situation. Please report it to the authors. Or may it was a deliberate decision. Meanwhile `git clone --filter=blob:none --reference blobless git@github.com:HaleTom/dotfiles.git new-clone` works for me. After that any access inside `new-clone` musr fetch required blobs.

Answer (score 1):

A partial clone is practically not going to work as a reference repository.  As you noted, creating a partial clone normally fetches missing objects from the promisor remote on demand.

However, fetches and clones from a remote repository don't read the configuration of the remote repository for security reasons, since a remote repository can't be trusted and the fetch or clone needs to be secure regardless.  (Configuration can contain arbitrary programs to execute.)  Additionally, fetching objects into the remote repository may or may not be possible, since it may be read-only, and the fetch or clone would be expected to function regardless.

Because `git clone` doesn't read the configuration of the remote repository, it's not going to know about the promisor remote and fill in any objects, so you'll need to use a non-partial clone if you want a reference repository.